# Rendering images and videos from same array in Gatsby/React/Graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a nested array via GraphQL from Contentful containing a number of posts. Each post contains (among other things) an array of images which U render in a loop to create a slideshow for each post. So far so good. But I want to be able to mix videos and images in slideshows and I'm stuck. A video src url breaks an image tag and vice versa. Is there a way to conditionally use an image or video tag based on the graphQL data? Or another solution?

Comment: Does the GraphQL response contain content-type by any chance?

Comment: No but I can pull the extension from:
...
items
  visuals {
     localFile {
        extension
     }
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have a function that tells you the type of file (video/image). Let that function be `getFileType(src)`:

```
const renderContent = (src) => {
    const fileType = getFileType(src);
    if (fileType == "image") {
        return <img src={src} />;
    } 
    else if (fileType == "video") {
        return <video><source src={src}></source></video>;
    }
    return null;
}
```